# Getting following error while inserting data in Ignite cache?

Tags: java, caching, ignite

This error is occurred while using JsonObject(GSON Library) in cache value if I used String instead of JsonObject then operation perform successfully.

**Error which I have get while inserting data in cache:**

```
javax.cache.CacheException: class org.apache.ignite.transactions.TransactionRollbackException: Transaction has been rolled back: 9557fcfb061-00000000-078a-a446-0000-000000000001
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1287)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.cacheException(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1648)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.put(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1008)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.put(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:872)
    at com.clouzer.databaseoperation.DataBaseOperation.getAllUSerGson(DataBaseOperation.java:527)
    at com.mstorm.ignition.gson.LoginCacheOperation.createLoginCache(LoginCacheOperation.java:38)
    at com.mstorm.ignition.gson.IgniteCacheCreator.createCaches(IgniteCacheCreator.java:30)
    at com.mstorm.ignition.gson.IgniteServer.main(IgniteServer.java:102)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.transactions.TransactionRollbackException: Transaction has been rolled back: 9557fcfb061-00000000-078a-a446-0000-000000000001
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$11.apply(IgniteUtils.java:860)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils$11.apply(IgniteUtils.java:858)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.internal.transactions.IgniteTxRollbackCheckedException: Transaction has been rolled back: 9557fcfb061-00000000-078a-a446-0000-000000000001
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.syncOp(GridCacheAdapter.java:4054)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.put0(GridCacheAdapter.java:2340)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.put(GridCacheAdapter.java:2321)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.put(GridCacheAdapter.java:2298)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxyImpl.put(IgniteCacheProxyImpl.java:1005)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Can not set final com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap field com.google.gson.JsonObject.members to java.util.LinkedHashMap
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.cast(IgniteUtils.java:7252)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.resolve(GridFutureAdapter.java:259)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get0(GridFutureAdapter.java:171)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.get(GridFutureAdapter.java:140)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearTxLocal$10.applyx(GridNearTxLocal.java:2396)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearTxLocal$10.applyx(GridNearTxLocal.java:2392)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteClosureX.apply(IgniteClosureX.java:38)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureChainListener.applyCallback(GridFutureChainListener.java:78)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureChainListener.apply(GridFutureChainListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureChainListener.apply(GridFutureChainListener.java:30)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.notifyListener(GridFutureAdapter.java:383)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.listen(GridFutureAdapter.java:353)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter$ChainFuture.<init>(GridFutureAdapter.java:572)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.future.GridFutureAdapter.chain(GridFutureAdapter.java:358)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearTxLocal.optimisticPutFuture(GridNearTxLocal.java:2391)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearTxLocal.putAsync0(GridNearTxLocal.java:622)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearTxLocal.putAsync(GridNearTxLocal.java:385)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$22.op(GridCacheAdapter.java:2342)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$22.op(GridCacheAdapter.java:2340)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.syncOp(GridCacheAdapter.java:4040)
    ... 9 more
```

**Cache Configuration:**

```
CacheConfiguration<String, JsonObject> cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration<>();
            cacheConfig.setName("CACHE_NAME");
            cacheConfig.setReadThrough(true);
            cacheConfig.setBackups(2);
            cacheConfig.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
            cacheConfig.setWriteThrough(true);
            cacheConfig.setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(ObjectLoader.class));
            IgniteCache<String, JsonObject> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheConfig);
```

**Operations:**

1.create JsonObject (use GSON library)

2.set cache loader to the given cache which used for persistent store

3.insert data into the cache from ignite client-side

4.observe the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `JsonObject` has `members` field of type `LinkedTreeMap`, and Ignite `BinaryMarshaller`, which is default one, deserializes it into a `LinkedHashMap` for some reason.

<s>To avoid it you can use a different marshaller, for example, `OptimizedMarshaller`.</s>

**UPD:**

Turns out, if you configure `OptimizedMarshaller`, then only puts and gets from cache will work fine. But if you try to `get(...)` some field of the deserialized representation of `JsonObject`, for example, then JVM will crash.

The reason is that `LinkedTreeMap` has the following `writeReplace()` method:

```
private Object writeReplace() throws ObjectStreamException {
    return new LinkedHashMap(this);
}
```

So, if you serialize it, and after that deserialize, then you will get an instance of `LinkedHashMap` instead of `LinkedTreeMap`. So, `BinaryMarshaller` is doing nothing wrong.

**Summary:**

Looks like you shouldn't put `JsonObject`s into cache. It doesn't implement `Serializable`, so the authors didn't think about serializing it. I think, you will have to replace `JsonObject` with JSON strings.